# Click event bubbling up in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm developing a project using Django 1.6. I have a pop up box which pops up when I click "Quick Upload" and there I'll be giving the path of a folder and say "OK".But the problem is when I click "OK" for one time then "function event()" is being called 4 times. Please help me in this regard. Code is shown below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value={{name}}>
<input id="button" onclick="quickupload();" class="css_button" value="Quick Upload">

<script>
function quickupload()
{
    $('div#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); 
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog
    ({
      resizable:true,
      height:150,
      modal: true,
      buttons: 
      {
        "OK": function event()
        { 
        var session1 = $("#name").val();
        var fpath = $("#quick1").val();
        listofpath=fpath.split("\\");
        finalpath="";   
        for (i=0;i<listofpath.length;i++)
        {
            finalpath=finalpath+listofpath[i]+"@";          
        }           
        console.log(finalpath);
        window.location.href = "/uploadquick/"+session1+"/"+finalpath;
        },
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you check with `event.stopPropagation` in the handler at the end?

Comment: share your complete `HTML`.

Comment: check here, http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/pxgodr47/ . It's being called a single time.

Comment: looks like you're creating the dialog every time you call `quickupload()`. Instead of creating a new dialog object every time, hold a reference to a single object outside and just toggle the dialog

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: Yes. I have looked into it. Still not helpful.

Comment: @AshadShanto : I wish I could but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a dialog object every time you call `quickupload()`. So the same handler you passed to `OK` in dialog definition is attached again and again on OK button every time you click on that `Quick Upload` button. Instead create a dialog object outside and then open on it you button click like this

```
<script>
// create the dialog object outside
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable:true,
      height:150,
      modal: true,
      buttons: 
      {
        "OK": function event()
        { 
        var session1 = $("#name").val();
        var fpath = $("#quick1").val();
        listofpath=fpath.split("\\");
        finalpath="";   
        for (i=0;i<listofpath.length;i++)
        {
            finalpath=finalpath+listofpath[i]+"@";          
        }           
        console.log(finalpath);
        window.location.href = "/uploadquick/"+session1+"/"+finalpath;
        },
      }
    });

function quickupload() {
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); 
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't want to load that pop up when page loads but I want to load this on clicking on button. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: That's what it does exactly. We're merely creating dialog but not showing it. We open the dialog only on click in `quickUpload()`. Have a look at the code again :-)